# Is there a simpler way to grep all files under a directory?

Tags: grep, find

When I want to search a whole tree for some content, I use

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep <search_string>
```

Is there a better way to do this in terms of performance or brevity?

Comment: @Downvoter: Happy to improve this question if you can share your concerns.

Comment: many find versions have xargs built in: find . -type f -exec fgrep <search_string> {} +

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Check if your `grep` supports `-r` option (for *recurse*):

```
grep -r <search_string> .
```

Comment: Yup... I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux and that's the answer there too.

Comment: add a comment about `--exclude-dir` to address performance and we have a winner!

Comment: Just notice that this is not portable, however `grep` on recent FreeBSD and Linux distros support it. And why `--exclude-dir`? Didn't you ask to *search a whole tree*?

Comment: Fair point... `--exclude-dir` is actually handy in my use case (because parts of the subtree are large, but useless) and I did ask about performance... but you're right, it's not necessary.

Comment: In this case I have to add that IIRC `--exclude-dir` is exclusive to GNU `grep`. (-:

Comment: If you are looking for content in files with a specific pattern you can add --include option (e.g. *.cpp if you want to look for content in C++ files). See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10619160/1967396)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to recurse down into subdirectories:

```
grep -R 'pattern' .
```

The `-R` option is not a standard option, but is supported by most common `grep` implementations.

Comment: Use `-r` instead of `-R` to skip symlinks when GNU grep is concerned

Comment: @AFSHIN Why would you not want to follow symlinks?

Comment: @Kusalananda Recursion? Although current GNU `grep` implementations catch recursions, I think. Otherwise it depends on what you mean by "tree".

Comment: @Philippos IMHO, babysitting the user is not something that a tool like `grep` should do. If the user has symbolic link loops in their directory structure, well, that's the user's problem  :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda And if the system provided the loop? Never got lost in `/sys/devices/cpu/subsystem/devices/cpu/subsystem/devices/cpu/...` (-X I like tools babysitting me (unless they provide weird magic they call "AI"). (-;

Comment: @Philippos `ls: /sys/devices: No such file or directory` Nope ;-)

Answer (score 12):

A sub optimal answer :
Instead of piping the output of `find` into `grep`, you could just run

```
find . -type f -exec grep 'research' {} '+'
```

and voila, one command instead of two !

explanation :

```
find . -type f
```

find all regular files within .

```
-exec grep 'research'
```

grep 'research'

```
{}
```

in found filename

```
'+'
```

use one command per all the filenames, not once per filename.

Nb : with `';'` it would have been once per filename.

Other than that, if you use that to process source code, you may look into `ack`, which is made for looking for code bits easily.

[ack](https://beyondgrep.com)

**Edit :**

You can extend that research a little. First, you can use the `-name ''` switch of `find` to look for files with specifig naming pattern.

For instance :

- only files that correspond to logs : `-name '*.log'`
- only files that correspond to c headers, but you can't stick with uppercase or lowercase for your filename extensions : `-iname *.c`

Nb : like for `grep` and `ack`, the `-i` switch means case insensitive in this case.

In that case, grep will show without color and without line numbers.

You can change that with the `--color` and the `-n` switches (Color and lines numbers in files respectively).

In the end, you can have something like :

```
find . -name '*.log' -type f -exec grep --color -n 'pattern' {} '+'
```

for instance

```
$ find . -name '*.c' -type f -exec grep -n 'hello' {} '+' 
./test2/target.c:1:hello
```

Comment: `ack` is great, and a faster version of `ack` is `ag` (the silver searcher, https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/)

Comment: I prefer this with filter like `-name '*.log'` It is faster.

Comment: @cfeduke I haven't tried it, mostly because ag isn't part of default apt repositories on WSL (you gotta work with what you have got !)

Comment: A trick is to add /dev/null to the grep to get the filename to appear.

Comment: A trick is to search only for directories and then -exec grep /dev/null {}/* to get  all files with single fork/exec per directory.

Answer (score 5):

As noted above `-r` or `-R` (depending on desired symlink handling) is a quick option.

However `-d <action>` can be useful at times.

The nice thing about `-d` is the skip command, which silences the "grep: 
directory_name: Is a directory" when you just want to scan the current level.

```
$ grep foo * 
grep: q2: Is a directory 
grep: rt: Is a directory 

$ grep -d skip foo *  
$
```

and of course:

```
$ grep -d recurse foo * 
(list of results that don't exist because the word foo isn't in our source code
and I wouldn't publish it anyway).  
$
```

The `-d skip` option is REALLY handy inside another script so you don't have to `2> /dev/null`. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a lot of files, the grep runs faster if you prune down the files it needs to search through rather than grepping all files in subfolders.

I use this format sometimes:

```
grep "primary" `find . | grep cpp$`
```

Find all files in subfolders of `.` that end in `cpp`. Then grep those files for "primary".

If you want, you can keep piping those results into further grep calls:

```
grep "primary" `find . | grep cpp$` | grep -v "ignoreThis" | grep -i "caseInsensitiveGrep"
```

Comment: backtics aren't good modern practice, they are all but obsolete

Comment: This will break if you have files with special characters in their names. I don't know how special they have to be in order to be too special for this to work as-is, but what you are doing is really much the same thing as parsing the output of ls, which is also bad.